# Save UIImageView Information

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I wanna save some `UIImageViews` with their pathes, coordinates and others, because in my app I can use fingers to pinch, rotate and pan the `UIImageView`.

What should I use to save these information?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly your problem is. You want to save them where? And why? And what is a "path" of an `UIImageView`?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is a bit unclear to me, but from what I understand

path - I couldn't find a trivial way to get path or file name

coordinate - `img_view.frame`

have a look at properties of `UIImageView` and `UIImage`